# The latest TagLib port for C#?

Tags: mono, taglib, taglib-sharp

Does anybody know where can I download C# wrapper for the latest TagLib version? The latest version I use is from the Mono package:
https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp

But it doesn't support tags of some WAV formats.

Comment: That is the canonical source repository.  There isn't anything newer.  Since TagLib# supports Wav/Riff files (ID3v2, RiffInfo, MovieID, DivX) can you provide details on your exact issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the GitHub location you mention is correct.  If you want tarballs (i.e. all the source), download them from the [Banshee location](http://download.banshee.fm/taglib-sharp/). I'd also agree with *Brian Nickel* the github location is the latest place to grab the source.